# browse under folders and files of a folder on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi all i am on laravel 7. I want to navigate through the folders and see their contents (subfolders and documents). To do this I used the following

```
    $directories = Storage::directories($path);
 
    $directories = Storage::files($path);
```

Here I will have two loops: one which will browse the documents and the other which will browse the folders.

I would like to have a way to travel the path in question and determine if I have a document or a folder.

thank you in advance

Comment: Are you want to know, how to get file from storage and check it is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Laravel 5.0 +, can use `$storage_path = storage_path().`
>
> storage_path Get the fully qualified path to the storage directory.
>
> You may also use the storage_path function to generate a fully
> qualified path to a given file relative to the storage directory:

$`path = storage_path('app/file.txt')`;

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers but I already understood all that if I would like for example to browse this directory on the image

[image]

Thank you for your answers but I have already understood all that I would like for example to browse this directory on the image how I should retrieve both the  folders and files. Is there a function that will make the difference between folders (Number and Times)  files on image.

Answer (score 0):

I have already seen the files and subfolders of storage_path() but I have them and recovered by two iterations

```
//for subfolders
$directories = Storage::directories($path);
//for files
$directories = Storage::files($path);
```

is there a way to do it with an iteration like scandir($path) and determine if the iterated item is a file or a directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this:

```
storage_path('directory-name/file-name');

OR

storage_path()/folder/filename;
```

For example, you might also need to traverse through multiple directory to access the file

```
storage_path('app/public/logos/medium/$image->filename') }}
```

This is also mentioned in laravel documentation, under [method-storage-path](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-storage-path)